# Unable to get String value Inside quote "" (Android)

Tags: java, android, string

I am passing string value from Activity class to non Activty class.But i want to put that string in Quotes and in Bracktes.I want just like this:

```
["getInterests"]
```

Following code i am using to get static variable from activity class :

```
str= MainActivity.getInterests;
            str1 = "\" +str+ \"";
            str2 = "["+str1+"]";
```

Comment: What's the question? Can you please be more descriptive as to what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work :

str2 = "[\""+str+"\"]";